# urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: webcal> when trying to write .ics file

Tags: python, html

I am trying to write the contents of a calendar (.ics) off a webpage (such as https://careers.unc.edu/calendar) into a file. Below is my code attempt:

```
def write_file(ics_url, set_calendar_name):

    url = ics_url

    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    webContent = response.read()

    f = open(set_calendar_name, 'w')
    f.write(webContent)
    f.close

    print 'File saved as: ' + set_calendar_name
    print
    return set_calendar_name
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "get_calendar.py", line 99, in <module>
  write_file(get_ics_url('https://careers.unc.edu/calendar'), 'carolina.ics')
File "get_calendar.py", line 36, in write_file
  response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 452, in _open
  'unknown_open', req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1266, in unknown_open
  raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: webcal>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what is causing it in my code? My program ran fine when I ran it with, for example, this URL: https://meded.hms.harvard.edu/calendar but not with the one mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I ended up figuring out what was wrong. The

```
link.get('href')
```

contained

```
'webcal:'
```

instead of

```
'https:'
```

at the beginning, so I had to replace it. The fixed code should be:

```
if link.get('href') != None and '.ics' in link.get('href'):
        endout = link.get('href')

        if endout[:6] == 'webcal':
            endout ='https' + endout[6:]
```